# Outside grid for fusor

Tags: electrostatics, fusion

I, for a while now, wanted to build a little Farnsworth desk [fusor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusor). Nothing too powerful, simply a small "desk lamp" if you will. As the fusor needs 2 grids, I was wondering, if it might be possible to position the outer grid outside of the vacuum chamber, as to make the inner grid a bit bigger. Just an idea, nothing solid yet. Just want to know if it's possible/feasable.

Comment: Well, what do those two grids do, and how is that impacted by having a material between them, either a metal or an insulator?

Comment: Well, a metal inbetween them would act as a faraday cage, but a vacuum itself acts like an insulator, so an insulator should be fine shouldn't it? Given that we don't have a perfect insulator, as soon as the voltage is high enough, a current should flow. I suppose the air around it would be ionized and then bombard the shell, but it should work, I think.